# Google Cloud PubSub python subscriber leaks memory

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, memory-leaks, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm facing a serious memory leak with memory intensive callback using Google PubSub client for python (https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub).

Details:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Python 3.8

Only 3 requirements:

- google-cloud-pubsub==2.4.1
- matplotlib==3.4.1
- memory-profiler==0.58.0

Take this simple "memory intensive" callback for example. If I run it as python function 4 times, this is what the memory graph looks like:

```py
from memory_profiler import profile

@profile
def callback():
    # Memory intensive operation
    x = [n for n in range(int(1e5))]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    callback()
    callback()
    callback()
    callback()
```

This is the graph plotted by memory_profiler
[image]

Everything looks fine here to me.

Now, if I use the same "memory intensive" function as pubsub callback and send 4 messages, this is what happens:

```py
import os
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from memory_profiler import profile

os.environ.setdefault('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS', 'path/to/key.json')
os.environ.setdefault('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT', 'project-id')
os.environ.setdefault('MY_TOPIC_NAME', 'test_memory_leak-sub')

topic_name = 'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic}'.format(
    project_id=os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
    topic=os.getenv('MY_TOPIC_NAME'),  # Set this to something appropriate.
)

subscription_name = 'projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{sub}'.format(
    project_id=os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
    sub=os.getenv('MY_TOPIC_NAME'),  # Set this to something appropriate.
)


@profile
def callback(message):
    # Memory intensive operation
    x = [n for n in range(int(1e5))]
    message.ack()
    print("ack")


with pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient() as subscriber:
    future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_name, callback)
    print("Starting subscriber")
    try:
        print("Listening...")
        future.result(timeout=30)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        future.cancel()
```

[image]
Here I'm facing a serious memory leak and it is evident because of the "huge" callback memory usage (?!)

It looks like the subscriber is leaking memory and the amount of memory leaked is directly proportional to the underlying callback memory usage, because leak amount is based on the callback memory usage. If callback "consumes" more memory, the leak gets worse. If the callback "consumes" less memory, the leak gets better. **Memory is released only on `future.result` timeout, exactly whe the future is canceled, so the actual workaround I'm using is to set a short timeout and wrap the message pull part in a `while True`, but this is not how the official documentation specifies to use the subscriber and does not solve the problem when 20 or 30 messages are pulled in the timeout window.**

It looks like the library is "caching" the callback somehow, but why?
How can I avoid this behavior?

This may be a bug of the library itself, but I'm not sure.

Comment: [Replied](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/273#issuecomment-817694171) on the GitHub issue. Does the graph look the same even if **not** explicitly importing the `profile` decorator in the test script?